# How can I mailmerge for each row of Google Sheets document to a Slides template (mail merge) using Apps Script if cell match?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, qr-code, mailmerge, google-slides-api

I created a spreadsheet that I used as checking in and checking out employees with QR Code and Google Forms. the script works and when I start it it also generates the google slides including the Qr code as an image.

My problem is that when I start the script it stops automatically after 6 minutes and I can not generate all rows of the table containing information. I want to create from row 2 to 601 (they are containing data) the slides with mailmerge. My idea is to tell the script that it should not automatically generate all rows but only if in column (O) as example the cells for each row contain an x. And I don't know how to do that.

I really dont now howHere is my script:

```
function mailMergeSlidesFromSheets() {
  // Load data from the spreadsheet
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange();
  var sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();

  // Save the header in a variable called header
  var header = sheetContents.shift();

  // Create an array to save the data to be written back to the sheet.
  // We'll use this array to save links to Google Slides.
  var updatedContents = [];

  // Add the header to the array that will be written back
  // to the sheet.
  updatedContents.push(header);

  // For each row, see if the 4th column is empty.
  // If it is empty, it means that a slide deck hasn't been
  // created yet.
  sheetContents.forEach(function(row) {
    if(row[2] === "") {
      // Create a Google Slides presentation using
      // information from the row.
      var slides = createSlidesFromRow(row);
      var slidesId = slides.getId();
   
      // Create the Google Slides' URL using its Id.
      var slidesUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${slidesId}/edit`;

      // Add this URL to the 4th column of the row and add this row
      // to the updatedContents array to be written back to the sheet.
      row[2] = slidesUrl;
      updatedContents.push(row);
    }
  });

  // Write the updated data back to the Google Sheets spreadsheet.
     dataRange.setValues(updatedContents);

}

function createSlidesFromRow(row) {
 // Create a copy of the Slides template
 var deck = createCopyOfSlidesTemplate();

 // Rename the deck using the firstname and lastname of the student
 deck.setName(row[0] + " " + row[5] + row[4] + row[10]);

 // Replace template variables using the student's information.
    deck.replaceAllText("{{id}}", row[0]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{tag}}", row[4]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{besetzung}}", row[5]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{beginn}}", row[6]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{ende}}", row[7]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{halle}}", row[8]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{stand}}", row[9]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{firma}}", row[2]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{veranstaltung}}", row[10]);
    deck.getSlides()[0].getShapes().find(s => s.getText().asString().trim().toUpperCase() == "{{IMAGE}}").replaceWithImage(`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=${row[13]}`);

 return deck;
}

function createCopyOfSlidesTemplate() {
 //
 var TEMPLATE_ID = "1bcIS7K-CH9KH0IixCKehFniCgAReZEH3m84pd5UxhFg";

 // Create a copy of the file using DriveApp
 var copy = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy();

 // Load the copy using the SlidesApp.
 var slides = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId());

 return slides;
}

function onOpen() {
 // Create a custom menu to make it easy to run the Mail Merge
 // script from the sheet.
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("⚙️ Create BWN by Pavlos")
   .addItem("Create Slides","mailMergeSlidesFromSheets")
   .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I want from the spreadsheet to create the slides with the data inside. The script looks at column C if a generated link is in it from the slide. If not then the script generates the slide if the condition on column L is JA.

And, your following new request,

> I want to convert automatically the slides to pdf .

In this case, please modify `mailMergeSlidesFromSheets` as follows.

Modified script:

```js
function mailMergeSlidesFromSheets() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();
  sheetContents.shift();
  var updatedContents = [];
  var check = 0;
  sheetContents.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[2] === "" && row[11] === "JA") {
      check++;
      var slides = createSlidesFromRow(row);
      var slidesId = slides.getId();
      var slidesUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${slidesId}/edit`;
      updatedContents.push([slidesUrl]);

      slides.saveAndClose();
      var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=${slidesId}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob().setName(slides.getName() + ".pdf");
      DriveApp.createFile(pdf); // Or DriveApp.getFolderById("###folderId###").createFile(pdf);

    } else {
      updatedContents.push([row[3]]);
    }
  });
  if (check == 0) return;
  sheet.getRange(2, 4, updatedContents.length).setValues(updatedContents);
}
```

Comment: thx for your reply. I get this error with your second solution. Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. In the data it is 1, but in the range 601.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pEdfnrp-YlUwdsELGz3qFUfKOSrwrkCJPgjV5IQIBPw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the spreadsheet I am using

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying and providing the sample spreadsheet. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the images are put over column "O". About your current issue, I think that the reason for this is due to `updatedContents` has not value. So, in your Spreadsheet, no value of `x` is put on the column "O". Please be careful about this. If you want to remove this issue, please put `if (updatedContents.length == 0) return;` just before the line of `dataRange.setValues(updatedContents);` and test it again.

Comment: Thx for your Reply before i test it i must say tha t the images in cillumn O will be deletet because i dont need them. I only need the images in collumn P. So if i delete the Images how is than the code? I delete some images now so you can see because i have shared the spreadsheet Thx for your time

Comment: Arigato! It works now but it seems it is not writing the generated url from the slide in collumn C. I left it blank so appscript save the generated url from the slide to look after and not generate again all the rows with x in ´side the cell in O. did make something wrong? And the sript generats now the slides correctly but the exception exists : Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. There are 3 in the data, but 601 in the range.

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About `if (updatedContents.length == 0) return;`, when I saw your script, it seems that your initial value of `updatedContents` has a header row. So, please add `if (updatedContents.length == 1) return;` as the above.

Comment: thx for Replying the error still exists bbut the slides are generating. As i saw the script cant see the cells in 0 if they have an x so the script tries i think to still generate.  if (row[2] === ""  if (row[2] === "" should actually look in column C if a link has been generated. If not, a slide of the line should be generated. However, the script does not add links in column C so that it can look. Or did I make something wrong here? Thx for your Support.

Comment: Ok I added another Collumn (A) at the beginning aof the sheet and the script stops after generating no Exception Error. But still no links are stored in the Collum D.

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About your new issue, I updated the modified scriptt. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Pavlos About `But still no links are stored in the Collum D.`, from your reply, I thought that you might have wanted to put the links to column "C". I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. If you want to put it to the column "D", please modify `updatedContents.push([row[2]]);` to `updatedContents.push([row[3]]);`, and `sheet.getRange(2, 3, updatedContents.length).setValues(updatedContents);` to `sheet.getRange(2, 4, updatedContents.length).setValues(updatedContents);`.

Comment: Is it possible to paste the right hole script because i think i maked someting wrong because the script starts no errors and nothing happens. The spreadsheet is shared so i think you can see the code also. Thx for your time.

Comment: Ok i got it working again.The Script generates the slides but no url from the genereted slides appears in the collumn D and i got this   ReferenceError: sheet is not defined
mailMergeSlidesFromSheets @ Code.gs:32

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. And, when you show your current script, please don't add it to my answer.

Comment: thx for your reply. with your script i got this error now.   SyntaxError: Illegal return statement Zeile: 26 Datei: Code.gs. i paste your script from the beinning till    if (updatedContents.length == 1) return;

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `with your script i got this error now. SyntaxError: Illegal return statement Zeile: 26 Datei: Code.gs. i paste your script from the beinning till if (updatedContents.length == 1) return;`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script using your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs. I apologize for no error. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script of my proposed script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Pavlos By the way, my added proposed script doesn't use `if (updatedContents.length == 1) return; `. So, I'm worried that you might have not tested my proposed script.

Comment: Sorry my faulth. Now the script is running but nothing is created. I dont no want Ia am doing wrong.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pEdfnrp-YlUwdsELGz3qFUfKOSrwrkCJPgjV5IQIBPw/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thris my spreadsheet

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About `Now the script is running but nothing is created.`, I think that the reason for this is due to `if (row[2] === "" && row[14] === "x") {` is false, in this case, please confirm your Spreadsheet again. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that column "O" has no value "x". I think that the reason of this is due to this.

Comment: @Pavlos When I saw your provided multiple Spreadsheets, it seems that you often change the specification of the Spreadsheet. I think that in this case even when I modified your script, my proposed script might not been correctly run by your changing specification. I'm worried about this.

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble Iam always trying.  Due to if (row[2] === "" && row[14] === "x") {  I have wrote in the script  if (row[2] === "" && row[13] === "JA") { I appologiize if that is not correct. Must I change it back ?

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About `Due to if (row[2] === "" && row[14] === "x") { I have wrote in the script if (row[2] === "" && row[15] === "JA") { I appologiize if that is not correct. Must I change it back ?`, it seems that you changed the specification again. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for your latest specification. I deeply apologize for this. Your often changing specification is confusing me. Can I ask you about your actual expected true goal?

Comment: Ok I am so sorry for the trouble. I want from the spreadsheet to create the slides with the DAta inside. The script looks at collumn C if a generated link is in it from the slide. If not then the script generates the slide if the contition on Collum L is JA. Sorry for bat Englisch. I wont change anything now,

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About `I want from the spreadsheet to create the slides with the DAta inside. The script looks at collumn C if a generated link is in it from the slide. If not then the script generates the slide if the contition on Collum L is JA.`, this is your final expected result? If it's so, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for the latest specification? By this, I would like to update my proposed script.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pEdfnrp-YlUwdsELGz3qFUfKOSrwrkCJPgjV5IQIBPw/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thris is the Spreadsheet I am using.

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About your final expected result, I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Arigatoooooooo!!!!!!!! @Tanaike thank you so much it works now like A charm. I want to convert automatically the slides to pdf . Must  I write a sepatet Question or can we do it right now?

Comment: @Pavlos About `Arigatoooooooo!!!!!!!! @Tanaike thank you so much it works now like A charm.`, I understood that your expected result was achieved. About your new question of `I want to convert automatically the slides to pdf .`, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. By the way, when your issue was resolved, please accept the answer.

Comment: thank you for your efort your work and your Time. The script works. Is it possible to Safe the generated pdf in separetet folder? The forlder ID is 1wXtTBOi4l5p5zOF6bPi3xFDx-WTIPljZ   i dont want to do it my self because IAm scared to make mistakes again! And is it possible to donate to you guys as I want to support you for you time and Help.

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About your new question of `Is it possible to Safe the generated pdf in separetet folder?`, please modify `DriveApp.createFile(pdf);` to `DriveApp.getFolderById("1wXtTBOi4l5p5zOF6bPi3xFDx-WTIPljZ").createFile(pdf);`.

Comment: @Pavlos About `And is it possible to donate to you`, thank you for it. In this case, I have [https://tanaikech.github.io/donate/](https://tanaikech.github.io/donate/). Is this useful?

Comment: @Pavlos But, first, please test the above modification.

Comment: the above Modifikation works as expected. The script generates the slides and the Pdf.

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About `the above Modifikation works as expected. The script generates the slides and the Pdf.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issues were resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer